# Send data with ajax but empty $_POST in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to save a data attribute of a div on click into a variable PHP. So I used $.ajax to send data with POST but it return an empty array. 
However, the POST is visible in the console with good data.

**AJAX**

```
$('.get-thumbnail-id').click(function() {
    var thumbnail_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gallery.php/",
        data: {thumbnail_id: thumbnail_id}
    });
});
```

**GALLERY.PHP**

```
var_dump($_POST['thumbnail_id']);
```

I must have done something wrong but I really don't know what... any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing

```
var_dump($_POST['thumbnail_id']);
```

Because the POST variable you are passing in the AJAX call has name `thumbnail_id` not just `id`

and check it with

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gallery.php/",
        data: {thumbnail_id: thumbnail_id},
        success : function(data){console.log(data);}
    });
```

Check whether is prints anything in the console.

Comment: Yes sorry, wrong copy and past but this is not working

Comment: See the updated answer. `echo` the variable in php instead of var_dump and then make AJAX call and then check console.

Comment: echo also return null. The console.log(data) seems to works, it return me the good id :   56string(2) "56"

Comment: If console.log(data) is working that means the data is going to the PHP file. And if you try to access the PHP file directly it won't print aything. I hope you understand that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Tell me what do you want to achieve after making this AJAX call?

Comment: I have a gallery photo displayed with a request to my database. When I click on a thumbnail, I want to display a popup with new information. So I want to save the ID of the thumbnail to do a new request with this ID of my thumbnail. So I would like to save the POST in a variable to use it in my request to my database.

Comment: Then in the PHP file just query the database with the POST var you are fetching. It will work. :) And in response just send the array or object of the new information which you can recieve in `data` var inside `success` function.